# Should we begin migrating questions to ELU?

Tags: discussion, migration, english-language-and-usage

The most serious death threat for ELL [has been](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120/what-are-the-criteria-for-surviving-to-public-beta):

> TPTB will be watching this very closely and if we basically create a copy of ELU, they will shut ELL down before it sees the light of public beta.

EL&U had [decided](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3674/9505) not to migrate questions here yet - to let us constitute ourselves, define who we are without them butting in with questions "they don't want", and instead encouraging askers to come here through comments.

But what about migration in the opposite direction? Questions [too](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/708/why-do-some-words-end-with-or-and-others-with-er-or-ar) [advanced](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/849/how-is-a-not-cut-in-printed-index-called#comment1105_849) for ELL and simply matching ELU better happen and will happen.

Technically, so far, before a migration path is established, this is done by picking "Flag",  "it needs ♦ moderator attention", "other" and typing "belongs to ELU". Once several such migrations happen, a path will be created.

Still, the question is: **Should we?**

My personal opinion:

While ELU has nothing to lose by not migrating "our" questions our way, and I appreciate their courtesy of "letting us define ourselves", we have everything to lose by not shaping ourselves to be different than ELU, so count my vote as "yes".

Comment: You could put your opinion as an answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes , if the ELL community decides that a question is more suitable for ELU then I cannot see any reason for not to migrate the question.

Really, to **keep questions which have no value to ELL** (most of the people read the question and have no idea how they could use the information) **just for having more questions will do us no good**. What is more, I do not have the feeling that we are lack of questions so far.

And as you mentioned, we should be shaping ourselves and I believe that after some time majority of people who will visit ELL will not visit ELU and vice versa, simply because of difference in their needs.

Answer (score 1):

No. We should jealously guard our questions. If a question is off topic, close it. Do not spend time thinking about EL&U.

EL&U is more prominent than ELL, so it seems unlikely that someone will find us before them.

I'm not suggesting we don't have enough questions. I am saying that when defining our scope we should not worry about what questions EL&U accepts. There will be overlap. That is OK.

Worrying about the suitablility of a question here by thinking if you would ask it on EL&U is asking us to take them into account before taking into account our own criteria. EL&U should not be in our thoughts at all. This stance might change if we get out of beta, but in these early stages, for the purposes of topicality, just pretend EL&U doesn't exist.